# AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen, naudio

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I am trying to convert a

```
PCM S16 LE (araw)
Mono, Sample rate 22050, Bit pr. sample 16
```

to

```
PCM mulaw (PCM MU-LAW)
Mono, Sample rate 8000hz, Bit pr. sample is 8.
```

`WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat(8000,1)` or even a more generic `WaveFormat.CreateCustomFormat` where I have specified the same `WaveFormatEncoding` as the source stream is throwing the same exception.

```
AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen
```

Am I missing something here?

Any leads will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really means "Conversion not possible".  Forget about ulaw, it is ancient.

Comment: @HansPassant it may be ancient but it is still in use all over place unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ACM mu-law encoder expects its input to be 16 bit. If you're working with mu or a-law, the sample rate is likely to be low as well. The following two lines of code will create a zero-length stream of PCM 16 bit and pass it into a WaveFormatConversionStream to convert it to a-law. It should not throw a "conversion not possible" error unless for some reason you don't have the G.711 encoder installed on your machine.

```
var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(), new WaveFormat(8000,16,1));
var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000,1), s);
```

Comment: How can I use this?