# NAudio error when adjusting volume of wave file

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

**Desired Outcome: Allow users to manipulate the volume of an audio file.**

I am trying to adjust the volume property of a wave file by creating a new file and adjusting the volume property. Each attempt has caused a different issue.

The following results in a `AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen` error:

```
WaveFormat target = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
var reader = new AudioFileReader(textBox2.Text);
reader.Volume = 0.5f;

using (WaveFormatConversionStream str = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, reader))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(textBox2.Text, str);
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628145/acmnotpossible-calling-acmstreamopen-naudio) suggested getting around the problem by `RawSourceWaveStream` but it keeps creating a file with a length of 0:00. I have tried passing an int as an argument for the `MemoryStream` with the same result and no way to assign a new value to the volume property.

Comment: There is no `volume` property of a Wave file.  The current playback volume can be adjusted but it has no effect on the file.

Comment: Note: the post you have linked to, does not talk about volume and it indicates clearly in the accepted answer: _"...the following two lines of code **will create a zero-length stream of PCM 16 bit** and..."_

Comment: @DavidTansey How can the volume of a file be manipulated then? Audio file manipulation software like Cool Edit allows for that sort of thing. I'm trying to recreate that functionality.

Comment: Why are you using a `WaveFormatConversionStream`? You could just pass the reader into `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16`